# Auto increment único em todas as tabelas do DB

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá, meu DB tem várias tabelas que possuem a mesma coluna:

```
`PROD` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Essa coluna é um identificador que faz um que faz um increment a cada lançamento.
A questão é preciso que ela receba o mesmo valor das outras tabelas, ou seja ele precisa ser único como se essa coluna fosse a mesma em todas as tabelas.

**Por exemplo** : Se eu faço um lançamento na tabela1 e essa coluna apresentar o valor 125 e após isso fazer o lançamento na tabela2 esse valor deve ser 126, ou seja ele somou com o valor da outra tabela mesmo sem ter recebido o lançamento, pois no meu caso ela está contando apenas os lançamentos na própria tabela sem levar em consideração os lançamentos já efetuados em outras.

Comment: me parece uma gambiarra... se você especificar o que seria tabela1 e tabela2, talvez possamos entender melhor o que precisa.

Comment: a tabela1 por exemplo seria de compra e a tabela2 de venda por exemplo, caso eu faça um lançamento na tabela de compra a tabela de venda não recebera nada, mas aumentaria o increment dela em +1 para os dois possuírem o mesmo valor no lançamento que está sendo representado pela coluna PROD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Em postgres, você poderia utilizar herança entre as tabelas:

```
Tabela "Transacoes"
id | data

Tabela "Vendas" que herda "Transacoes"
cliente

Tabela "Compras" que herda "Transacoes"
fornecedor
```

> Mas no Mysql creio que não há essa opção. Logo, trabalharia com apenas uma tabela:

```
"Transacoes"
id   |   data     |   emitente    |    destinatario    |  tipo    | numero
1    | 31/10/2017 |  "Voce"       |   "Ciclano"        |  "Venda" |   1
2    | 30/10/2017 |"Fornecedor X" |   "Voce"           | "Compra" |   1
3    | 29/10/2017 |  "Voce"       |   "Fulano"         |  "Venda" |   2
4    | 28/10/2017 |  "Voce"       |   "Maria"          |  "Venda" |   3
5    | 27/10/2017 |  "Voce"       |   "Joao"           |  "Venda" |   4
6    | 26/10/2017 |"Fornecedor A" |   "Voce"           | "Compra" |   2
```

.     **V**ocê até pode alterar a sequencia de outra tabela seja por trigger ou definindo uma sequencia apenas para as duas tabelas, mas não vejo o porque fazer isso. Se vão estar em tabelas separadas, não conseguirá fazer uma FK para a chave que precisa.

.    **T**ambém é possível adicionar uma terceira tabela que relacione os códigos das vendas, com os de compras e os produtos, mas aí depende da sua necessidade e modelo.

Answer (score 1):

O auto incremento é individual de cada tabela. Para padronizar seus IDs, você pode controlar através da sua aplicação ou trigger/função, onde recuperaria o ID da gerado na tabela que deseja e iria atualizar a coluna correspondente nas outras tabelas. Mas se tratando de um banco de dados relacional, você pode pensar em criar um relacionamento entre elas e assim, recuperar seus registros de forma mais integra e independe do ID de cada tabela.

Comment: Acha que no caso seria mais viável fazer esse incremento através do código quando fizer o lançamento? Havia pensado nisso mas como tenho várias opções de lançamento adicionar um código em cada uma ficaria difícil, ainda sim viável.

Comment: Se você realmente precisar manter os IDs iguais, seria uma forma prática de controlar, pois poderia deixar os registros preparados no insert. Lembrando que seria interessante manter uma transação para manter a integridade em caso de falha em uma das tabelas.